# How to get Stringify specific column value with many braces

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, stringify

I am new at java spring web mvc and im currently trying to create an ajax response using spring controller.

Here is my code:

**Controller Class**

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class AppController {

        @Autowired
        EmployeeService service;

        @Autowired
        MessageSource messageSource;

            @RequestMapping(value = { "/editAjax-{ssn}-employee" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Employee check1(@PathVariable String ssn,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Employee employee = service.findEmployeeBySsn(ssn);
        return employee;
    }
    }
```

**Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 200)
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 8, fraction = 2)
    @Column(name="SALARY", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal salary;


    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="SSN", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String ssn;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate joiningDate;



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((ssn == null) ? 0 : ssn.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (ssn == null) {
            if (other.ssn != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ssn.equals(other.ssn))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address
                + ", salary=" + salary + ", ssn=" + ssn + ", joiningDate="
                + joiningDate + "]";
    }

    // Empty Constructor
    public Employee() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public LocalDate getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }

    public void setJoiningDate(LocalDate joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

}
```

and here is my script inside jsp

```
<script>
        /* This function provide response from controller retrieving employee
         * detail via ssn id.
         */
        function searchViaAjax(obj) {
            var stringResponse;
            var id = obj.id;
            $.ajax({

                /* Controller Request Mapping */
                url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editAjax-${'" + id
                        + "'}-employee",
                type : "GET",
                contentType : "application/json",
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(response) {

                    /* Convert response into String */
                    stringResponse = JSON.stringify(response, [ 'id', 'name',
                            'address', 'salary', 'ssn', 'joiningDate' ]);

                    console.log(stringResponse);

                },
                error : function(e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

**console result:**

```
sucess! {"id":6,"name":"test","address":"Makati city","salary":124565,"ssn":"2","joiningDate":{}}
```

As you can see i failed to get the joiningDate value.

When i access the web url directly the output of response is this. All works fine i get the value of id,name,address,salary,ssn,joiningDate.

But in joiningDate there are so many braces and fields i think because of the type in model class that set into org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate? How can i get only atleast the "values":[2018,3,27] in joiningDate field?

Is there a way to retrieve the values that i want only despite in many values inside joiningDate? Do i need to change the type in my model class?

{"id":6,"name":"test","address":"Makati city","salary":124565,"ssn":"2",**"joiningDate":{"dayOfMonth":27,"dayOfWeek":2,"era":1,"year":2018,"dayOfYear":86,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"}},"weekyear":2018,"monthOfYear":3,"yearOfEra":2018,"yearOfCentury":18,"centuryOfEra":20,"weekOfWeekyear":13,"fields":[{"lenient":false,"maximumValue":292278993,"minimumValue":-292275054,"rangeDurationField":null,"leapDurationField":{"unitMillis":86400000,"precise":true,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"durationField":{"unitMillis":31556952000,"precise":false,"name":"years","type":{"name":"years"},"supported":true},"name":"year","type":{"durationType":{"name":"years"},"rangeDurationType":null,"name":"year"},"supported":true},{"lenient":false,"maximumValue":12,"minimumValue":1,"rangeDurationField":{"unitMillis":31556952000,"precise":false,"name":"years","type":{"name":"years"},"supported":true},"leapDurationField":{"unitMillis":86400000,"precise":true,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"durationField":{"unitMillis":2629746000,"precise":false,"name":"months","type":{"name":"months"},"supported":true},"name":"monthOfYear","type":{"durationType":{"name":"months"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"years"},"name":"monthOfYear"},"supported":true},{"maximumValue":31,"minimumValue":1,"rangeDurationField":{"unitMillis":2629746000,"precise":false,"name":"months","type":{"name":"months"},"supported":true},"lenient":false,"unitMillis":86400000,"durationField":{"unitMillis":86400000,"precise":true,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"name":"dayOfMonth","type":{"durationType":{"name":"days"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"months"},"name":"dayOfMonth"},"supported":true,"leapDurationField":null}],"values":[2018,3,27],"fieldTypes":[{"durationType":{"name":"years"},"rangeDurationType":null,"name":"year"},{"durationType":{"name":"months"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"years"},"name":"monthOfYear"},{"durationType":{"name":"days"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"months"},"name":"dayOfMonth"}]}**}

**UPDATE:**

When i try to remove the @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate") i got an error. it says **could not deserialize**.

```
Apr 05, 2018 12:50:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/MavenTry] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303138
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at com.websystique.springmvc.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.findAllEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:44)
    at com.websystique.springmvc.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.findAllEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.findAllEmployee(Unknown Source)
    at com.websystique.springmvc.controller.AppController.employeeList(AppController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For The full code reference. This is the tutorial of this program. http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/

Comment: Try after removing @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")

Comment: I try to remove but i got error. I update my post sir

Comment: instead of using LocalDate , use Date object like this :       
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date joiningDate;

Comment: Thanks Sanjay it work now but the output of dateformat is stringResponse {"id":20,"name":"test delete","address":"Pandi Bulacan","salary":124565,"ssn":"12322","joiningDate":"2018-03-27"}. Thanks bro